# Edit strings of exe file with no resources

Tags: windows, visual-basic, reverse-engineer

I am trying to edit some hardcoded textstrings of a simple application called [mininotify](http://www.myitforum.com/Forums/tm.aspx?m=176854), because I want to do some translation. The program  has been abandoned by its developer some years ago, and he doesn't answer when I contact him.

The application seems to be written in Microsoft Visual basic.

I have tried to use tools like Resource hacker and Resource tuner, but the application does not have any strings saved as resources.

I have also tried to find strings by searching with HEX-editor, but I only find programming variables and stuff like that.

Is there anything else I can do, or is it impossible?

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution to this issue ? I ran into the same problem and I am still trying to find a solution in vain :)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like [.Net Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) its not free anymore, but there is a 14 day trial.

Comment: .. isn't it just for .net apps?

Comment: So I need to decompile the whole application, change strings and the fix all errors and then recompile it? Seems like a lot of work.

Comment: Apologies, I was thinking about VB.NET. Probably wont work. you need to find a visual basic decomiler, and then hope that it was not obfuscated.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you dont see any strings is probalby fact that exe is packed with **UPX** or other executable packer. I tryed download the file to determine which packer was used but program is no longer available on server. Post the program if You can, i'll try help.

Comment: Look here: http://myitforum.com/cs2/files/folders/utilities/entry114775.aspx